# New project using git and remote server

Tags: git

I started working with git and i have some basic knowledge about how to use it.
Played around with it, working with branches, the usual stuff ... but now i want to start a new project and deploy it into production, so others can see the work so far. And i am a bit stuck.

What i have so far:

- created an empty repository on a remote server
- 2 branches (master and develop on witch i will create/merge other small tasks branches )
- i cloned the repository locally so i can work on new features

Let's say i finished the first task (as a branch), merged it locally on develop, and then push it to the remote server (in develop).

But i would like to create a new project, also on that remote server so my friends can see the status of the project, or maybe test the new feature i added.
My first thought was to create a folder in /var/www, and clone the repository there ( + checkout develop ). And every time i want to update the project, i could pull from develop and have the changes there.
Is it ok, or is there a different approach, and maybe better. I want things to be organized.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're writing makes a lot of sense. Clone the repo on the server in your document root, and then update it when you are ready.

As you move forward with this model, you might want to look into Git-Flow, which goes a bit beyond what you're currently doing, adding support for releases, feature branches and hotfixes.

In your case, you would be using the *master* branch for the document root, since it contains the stable releases.

Check out the following links for a description of Git-Flow:

- http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
- https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow

If you want to automated deployment when you make changes, you could look into automatically pulling changes as you make them. Here's an article with an overview on how to use them for development and deployment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks